# Set property before update

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I read [Operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks) and understood the concept of "not tied to a particular method". So i would like to know if is possible to set a property before update a model.

I have a updatedAt property in my User model, and i want set it to `new Date();` in all calls to the PUT verb.

I didn't try anything, because i'm not finding a answer in the docs or in stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks):

```
module.exports = User => {
  User.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.instance) {
      ctx.instance.updatedAt = new Date()
    } else {
      ctx.data.updatedAt = new Date()
    }
    next()
  })
}
```

If you want to apply this common logic to the set of models, [mixins](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+mixins) are usually a way to go.

```
module.exports = (Model, options) => {
  Model.defineProperty('updatedAt', { type: Date, default: '$now' })

  Model.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.instance) {
      ctx.instance.updatedAt = new Date()
    } else {
      ctx.data.updatedAt = new Date()
    }
    next()
  })
}
```

In case you don't want to implement this yourself, there is a an [npm package](https://github.com/clarkbw/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin) for it available.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSchwarz!!